# How to handle a remote delete in the adapter?

Tags: websocket, ember-data

It seems that Ember-Data is very well suited to manage change originating from the client, and I've handled changing coming in realtime via websockets with `store.load(type, id, data)`, but I can't figure out how to tell the `store` that an object has been removed on the server and thus needs to be removed locally as well.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks!